Formula for filtering list based off of key with multiple criteria in Google Sheets
I have a set of rows by which I am trying to display filtered on a different sheet based off of a column that matches a key range.
I can get it to work if there is a single key. I am having trouble when there is a list of keys. (Comparing to each key individually and putting ANDs between them is not a good solution.)

Looking at the image above, when I use xMatch it only returns the first index instead of every match, otherwise it would work.
There's got to be a way to do it with filter too, but again, I can only get it to work with a single key, not all keys in a range.
How should I create the formula to get the desired result?
EDIT (removed google sheet link and added markdown table):
I am not sure if this is what is being requested, but I copied the cells and put it in a 'table to markdown' converter. Here is the result:



a
abacus

Formula:
`=CHOOSEROWS(A1:B10,arrayformula(XMATCH(B15:B17,A1:A10)))





b
baloney

a
abacus



c
cat

d
dog



a
airplane

c
cat



a
awesome






b
balloon






c
ate






d
dog

Formula:
`=filter(A1:B12,A1:A12=B15:B17)



d
danger

a
abacus



b
basketball

c
cat



e
elephant






e
electric









Desired output:
Formula= ???




Key

a
abacus




a

c
cat




d

a
airplane




c

a
awesome






c
ate






d
dog






d
danger













Kindly refrain from posting images of your spreadsheet and code blocks because Tables and Make an anonymous sample document can be utilized to create a minimal, reproducible example. Also, when you edit the question, please ask one question at a time, as Stack Overflow's goal is to help users solve their problems and is not a bespoke coding service.

I see you updated your comment. I will go to the link and try it

@brw59 We ask for copiable data so we do not need to recreate what you already created.  That way we can trouble shoot.  Remember we are all volunteers

And to answer your question a link to a temp google sheet is also not what @Saddles was asking.  They asked for a markdown table so the data stays with the question in the future and does not rely on a link that will die eventually.

I am confused how I am supposed to add the markdown table to the question. The link in the question above was created via the link that Saddles provided. I copied the link and posted it. Where do I go to add the document appropriately if posting the link isn't the correct way?

What should happen is you create some test data on something like google sheets or Excel then use a markdown table creator like this and post that in your question.

Hey @ScottCraner and Saddles, I just wanted to throw out a message of gratitude that you took the time to explain where I was lacking, the patience with my misunderstanding, and specifics on how clarity can be added to the question. Thanks again

Use REDUCE(LAMBDA())
=REDUCE({"clm1","clm2"},B15:B17,LAMBDA(_z,_y,vstack(_z,filter(A1:B12,A1:A12=_y))))



Thank you. I hadn't considered using lambda. I'll have to sit and think about how it works in google sheets, but it does what I want it to


You may try:
=filter(A1:B12,xmatch(A1:A12,B15:B17))



Another great answer and it is very straightforward. Thanks

You may try the following formula:
=FILTER(A1:B12,(A1:A12=B15)+(A1:A12=B16)+(A1:A12=B17))

Where B15, B16 and B17 are your keys.


I would like to arrive at this solution without treating B15, B16 and B17 separately and rather use it as a range. Unfortunately my real problem has a much longer list of keys and it would be impractical to repeat it for an unknown amount of keys

Another alternative using the QUERY function, which simulates a LEFT JOIN in SQL
=QUERY({A2:B},"Select Col1, Col2 Where Col1 Matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",,D2:D) & "' And Col1 Is Not Null Order By Col1 Asc")

.


Seems like another outside the box solution that didn't occur to me, using queries. Thanks
